# Insert a new node in complete Simple Binary Tree Recursively

Tags: recursion, binary-tree

How to achieve this functionality recursively:

```
Node root = new Node(5);
        root.left = new Node(10);
        root.right = new Node(15);
        root.left.left = new Node(20);
        root.left.right = new Node(25);
        root.right.left = new Node(30);
        root.right.right = new Node(35);
```

Note: This is not BST.

Comment: so you want the tree to be always complete (or if partially complete, that the last "row" is all to the left part)? Red Black Tree?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a better constructor?

```js
const Empty =
  Symbol()

const Node = (data, left = Empty, right = Empty) =>
  ({ data, left, right })
  
const root =
  Node
    ( 5
    , Node(10, Node(20), Node(25))
    , Node(15, Node(30), Node(35))
    )
 
console.log(root)
```